# Flutter clean and flutter run doesn't rebuild the app on macOS using Visual Studio Code

Tags: macos, flutter, visual-studio-code

On the **first compile** the project is build correctly and running on both device or simulator. After that if ***I apply a change on the code*** and try the **Hot Restart and rebuild** the app doesn't rebuild and does not show the new modification.

Even if I try `flutter clean` in order to clean the solution, Deleting the 'build/' path and `flutter run` after but the same issue occurs again.

Or  `rm -rf build && flutter run`

I've updated both the Visual Studio Code and Flutter (version 1.9) in order to be up to date retry but does not make any change at all.

I have tried to run the app from Xcode too after flutter clean and get the same issue.

Below I'm attaching a simple print screen in order to show a simple change I've applied on a demo project on the ***title string value*** and the solution on the simulator (the same one I get on physical device too) with the code modification, and the app that doesn't rebuild.

[image]

P.s: I've check this one too https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/17155

And this one https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/18736 deleting files in `ios/` and `android/`, running `flutter clean`, `flutter create .` in order to recreate the files and at the end `flutter run`

Comment: Try to run with `flutter run --verbose`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your screenshot, the `main.dart` file appears to be unsaved (it has a dot in the tab). If the changes aren't saved, reloading in the terminal won't apply those changes.

That said, there is a much better way than running `flutter run` from the Terminal - use `F5` (or **Debug -> Start Debugging**). When running that way, not only to you get a full debugger, you will get hot-reload-on-save as well as other debug functionality and easy access to DevTools!

There's more info on running and debugging in VS Code here:

https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/vs-code#running-and-debugging

Comment: Thank you @Danny Tuppeny, that was the issue.